# java does not return an error for Generic statement

Tags: java, class, generics, super, extend

Hello trying to find answer
c1 class is extended b1
b1 class is extended a1
a1 is super class

this chunk of code does not give an error.
What is wrong in the code ?

```
public static void append1(Collection<? super a1> my_array, int n) {
       
            my_array.add(new c1());
            my_array.add(new b1());
            my_array.add(new a1());
           
            
    }
```

Comment: Why you expect an error?

Answer (score 0):

Super class reference can hold the object of sub-class.

To understand better consider that you are not using generic.

```
public static void append1(Collection<a1> my_array, int n) {
       
    my_array.add(new c1());
    my_array.add(new b1());
    my_array.add(new a1());
}
```

You should be agreed to above code validity. As if we create the Collection of SuperClass we will be allowed to add any sub-class object to that.

Same thing is happening here with generics. When you declare below:

```
public static void append1(Collection<? super a1> my_array, int n) {
       
    my_array.add(new c1());
    my_array.add(new b1());
    my_array.add(new a1());
}
```

my_array is actually of super type. So you are allowed to add any child of that super class.

Then a question arise you is that, what is the use of generic then? What is the use of `super` there? So to answer that, is will be used when you will be calling that method from some another method. And there you will be able to pass list which is super to a1 only. Below will give you the error.

```
public static void main(final String[] args) {
    append1(new ArrayList<b1>()); // compilation error as b1 is not super to a1
    append1(new ArrayList<c1>()); // compilation error as c1 is not super to a1
}
```

Comment: Thank you notescrew , great explanation!

Comment: @yka Please consider accepting the answer, if it was helpful. So others with the same problem can consider this as correct answer.